# Why do I need a UnitOfWork in EntityFramework4 can you clarify?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am jumping on the bandwagon and starting to implement the UnitOfWork with repository pattern.
Still need to find an example that works with "Include".I am using Code generated by EF not poco.".Where I can Download one? I know I should have used poco" ,that is another story.

Now my question
Am I obviously missing the point.Why do I need a Unit Of work?

I have many transactions and I do Context.SaveChanges(); If something goes wrong it will all be rolled back no?
Isnt that what the UnitOfwork is about.? If that is the case EF4 already has a UnitOFwork built in in the OBjectContext.

Why the extra classes? Could you explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unit of Work is used to save across multiple repositories as part of a single transaction.

For instance, if you are working with a **UserRepository** and a **FooRepository**, if the first one passes, then the second one fails, then the transactions are out of sync.

Unit of Work is implemented as a wrapper for the ObjectContext, meaning you do your work on both repositories, then **Commit** on the UoW *once*, which handles changes across both repositories. If one or both of the operations fail, the whole transaction fails.

It depends on how you work with your ObjectContext. If you are directly using the object context, then you can wrap all your operations in a *using* statement. But most people access the context via a Repository (and dispose of the context using a DI container, or manually). In this cases, a Unit of Work is required for work with multiple repositories.

[Here is an example of EF4/Repository/UoW.](http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/06/28/entity-framework-repository-amp-unit-of-work-t4-template-on.aspx)

DDD purists would argue that a Unit of Work is not required for repositories when aggregate boundaries are correct.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply.At the moment I am working directly against the object context within a Using Statement like you say. So what you are saying is that if you are creating repository and therefore UnitTesting -MOcking them than you need a UnitOfWork.Otherwise the ObjectContext does exactly the same job.No?.Thanks for that link.However does example dont seem to handle include, or cannot figure out how he uses include.Without include it;s pretty useless to me. Again.Thanks for your reply.Have you implemented a UnitOfWork with Include?

Comment: Unit of Work has nothing to do with Include. I use both Unit of Work and Include. Include is done on the `ObjectSet<T>`. If your working directly against the context, then **you do not need a unit of work**. As i said, UoW is only for use with the Repository pattern. Doesn't have much to do with mocking either. Sure you can create an interface (IUnitofWork) and then mock that out, but you can do the same with IObjectContext. Overall, i don't think UoW is applicable to your scenario.

Comment: At the moment I am working agains the context,but I would like to start working against repositories instead.My understanding of the Repository pattern is "abstraction from datalayer" and code is more testable.Also do you have a noddy example of how you used include in your unit of work?thanks for you time

Comment: If you look at that link i sent you, he uses `IQueryable<T>` for his Find method in his Repository. I do the same. Are you familiar with `IQueryable<T>`? Basically, it uses *deferred execution*, so the query is not executed until something like `.ToList` or `.SingleOrDefault` is executed. `.Include` works off `ObjectQuery<T>`, which also implements `IQueryable<T>`. So what i do is *cast* the `IQueryable<T>` to `ObjectQuery<T>`, and `.Include` off that.

Comment: Example: `var query = repository.Find(x => x.Id == 1); query = ((ObjectQuery)query).Include("Something").ToList();` Do that in a extension method to hide away the cast.

Comment: Again - let me reinstate, `Include` has nothing to do with the Unit of Work. Unit of Work is a wrapper for the ObjectContext. Include works off the ObjectSet.

Comment: Oh and a final point, the example i sent you uses a *generic* repository. You don't HAVE to use this. You can create a *specific* repository which has more explicitly named methods - e.g "FindSomethingSpecific(int specificId)", as opposed to just "Find". In that case, you can do the `.Include` in the method itself.

Comment: @RPM1984.THANKS for your time.It's starting to click in my brain.

Comment: @user231465 - pleasure, glad i could help. :)